# What is $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{k^nz^k}{k!}$?

Tags: taylor-expansion, exponential-function

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Can you find a simple expression for the function

$f_n(z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{k^nz^k}{k!}$.

By simple expression I just mean a finite linear combination of powers of $z$, exponential functions, (or something else?)

---

For example in the case $n=1$, we have

$f_1(z)=ze^z$.

I am really struggling to see an expression for the general $n\in\mathbb{N}$ case. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consider $z=e^x$.  Then we have:

$$g_n(x)=f_n(e^x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{k^ne^{kx}}{k!}\\g_0(x)=e^{e^x}$$

Likewise, one can easily see that this is the $n$th derivative of $g_0(x)$:

$$k^ne^{kx}=\frac{\partial^n}{\partial x^n}e^{kx}$$

Thus,

$$g_n(x)=\frac{\partial^n}{\partial x^n}e^{e^x}$$

And by [Faà di Bruno's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula),

$$g_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n e^{e^x}\cdot B_{n,k}(\underbrace{e^x,e^x,\dots,e^x}_{n-k+1})$$

Where $B_{n,k}$ is a [Bell polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_polynomial).  Now just substitute $x=\ln(z)$ to get

$$f_n(z)=\sum_{k=1}^n e^z\cdot B_{n,k}(\underbrace{z,z,\dots,z}_{n-k+1})$$

---

This is also known as a [Touchard polynomial](http://Touchard%20polynomials).  We have:

$$f_n(z)=e^zT_n(z)=e^z\sum_{k=0}^n\left\lbrace {n \atop k}\right\rbrace z^k=e^z\sum_{k=0}^n\frac1{k!}\sum _{j=0}^k(-1)^{k-j}\binom kjj^nz^k$$

Where $\left\lbrace {n \atop k}\right\rbrace$ is a [Stirling number of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind).

Answer (score 6):

\begin{align}
f_{n+1}(z)&=\sum_{k\ge 1}\frac{k^{n+1}z^k}{k!}=z\sum_{k\ge 0}\frac{(k+1)^{n}z^{k}}{k!}\\
&=z\sum_{i=0}^n\sum_{k\ge 0}\binom{n}{i}\frac{k^iz^{k}}{k!}
\\
&=z\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{n}{i}f_i(z).
\end{align}

Comment: This is clearly the best answer.

Comment: @IvanDiLiberti I'd say its arguable whether this gives a closed expression for general $n\in\mathbb N$.  The recurrence formula is very messy to use and becomes increasingly unwieldy for large $n$.

Comment: For large $n$, I think differentiation is easier, as it only relates $f_{n+1}(z)$ to $f_n(z)$, and the differentiation process isn't too hard.

Answer (score 5):

In terms of [Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind) for any $n\geq 1$ we have
$$ k^n = \sum_{j=1}^{n}{n \brace j}\binom{k}{j}j! \tag{1}$$
and since
$$ \sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{z^k}{k!}\binom{k}{j}j! = z^j e^z \tag{2}$$
it follows that
$$ \sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{k^n z^j}{k!} = e^z\sum_{j=1}^{n}{n\brace j}z^j\tag{3} $$
so the wanted series is the product between $e^z$ and a [Bell polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_polynomials).

Answer (score 3):

A similar trick should work always$$(ze^z)'= \sum \frac{k(k-1)z^k}{k!} = \sum \frac{k^2z^k}{k!} - \sum \frac{kz^k}{k!} = \sum \frac{k^2z^k}{k!} - ze^z.$$